# Authenticate Dovecot against Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, dovecot, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to authenticate Dovecot against a Microsoft Active Directory on a Windows 2008 R2 Domain Controller. Dovecot (Version 2.2.9) is running on Ubuntu 14.04 (3.13.0-30-generic).

My Configs:

dovecot.conf

```
protocols = imap

service imap {
inet_listener = *:143
}

auth_username_format = %Lu
auth_mechanisms = plain login

disable_plaintext_auth = no
ssl = no

mail_location = maildir:/var/vmail/%u/Maildir

first_valid_uid = 1001
last_valid_uid = 1001

first_valid_gid = 1001
last_valid_gid = 1001

valid_chroot_dirs = /var/vmail

passdb {
      driver = ldap
      args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-ldap.conf
}

userdb {
      driver = ldap
      args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-ldap.conf
}

log_path = /var/log/dovecot.log
syslog_facility = local7
auth_debug=yes
```

dovecot-ldap.conf

```
hosts = dc.testdomain.local
dn = CN=scanner,OU=SpecialUsers,DC=testdomain,DC=local
dnpass = scanner
ldap_version = 3
base = DC=testdomain,DC=local
scope = subtree
user_attrs = sAMAccountName=home
user_filter = (&(ObjectClass=user)(|(mail=%u)(sAMAccountName=%u)))
pass_attrs = sAMAccount=user,userPassword=password
pass_filter = (&(ObjectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=%u))
default_pass_scheme = plain
```

I'm testing my Config with "telnet ub14-dovecot 143" and following commands:

```
Connected to ub14-dovecot.
Escape character is '^]'.
* OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE IDLE AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=LOGIN] Dovecot (Ubuntu) ready.
a1 login scanner scanner
* OK Waiting for authentication process to respond..
* BYE Disconnected for inactivity during authentication.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

The Log:

```
Jul 22 13:08:46 auth: Debug: Loading modules from directory: /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/auth
Jul 22 13:08:46 auth: Debug: Loading modules from directory: /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/auth
Jul 22 13:08:46 auth: Debug: Module loaded: /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/auth/libauthdb_ldap.so
Jul 22 13:08:46 auth: Debug: Read auth token secret from /var/run/dovecot/auth-token-secret.dat
Jul 22 13:08:46 auth: Debug: auth client connected (pid=28292)
Jul 22 13:08:57 auth: Debug: client in: AUTH    1   PLAIN   service=imap    session=MQf5P8b+bACsEAgU    lip=172.16.1.78 rip=172.16.8.20lport=143    rport=36972 resp=    <hidden>
Jul 22 13:08:57 auth: Debug: ldap(scanner,172.16.8.20,<MQf5P8b+bACsEAgU>): pass search: base=DC=testdomain,DC=local scope=subtree filter=(&(ObjectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=scanner)) fields=uid,userPassword
Jul 22 13:11:46 imap-login: Info: Disconnected: Inactivity during authentication (disconnected while authenticating, waited 169 secs): user=<>, method=PLAIN, rip=172.16.8.20, lip=172.16.1.78, session=<MQf5P8b+bACsEAgU>
Jul 22 13:13:11 auth: Error: PLAIN(scanner,172.16.8.20,<MQf5P8b+bACsEAgU>): Request 28292.1 timed out after 254 secs, state=1
Jul 22 13:13:11 auth: Debug: client in: CANCEL  1
Jul 22 13:14:11 auth: Info: ldap(scanner,172.16.8.20,<MQf5P8b+bACsEAgU>): Shutting down
Jul 22 13:14:11 auth: Debug: client passdb out: FAIL    1   user=scanner    temp
```

As you can see I get a timeout from the AD. If i try to login with wrong credentials its the same. So I'm sure I have a error in my config. I'm just not able to find it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my config and it's working

```
cat /etc/dovecot/dovecot-ldap.conf
hosts = dc01.mydomain.tld
base = dc=mydomain, dc=tld
ldap_version = 3
auth_bind = yes
auth_bind_userdn = seta-int\%u
```

---

And here is my Auth. config
 dovecot -n

```
auth_debug = yes
auth_username_format = %Lu
listen = *
mail_location = maildir:/home/vmail/%u/Maildir
mbox_write_locks = fcntl
passdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-ldap.conf
  driver = ldap
}
protocols = imap pop3
ssl_cert = </etc/pki/dovecot/certs/dovecot.pem
ssl_key = </etc/pki/dovecot/private/dovecot.pem
userdb {
  args = uid=vmail gid=vmail home=/var/vmail/%u
  driver = static
}
```

**seta-int** is my Windows2000 and previous compatibility domain as Windows requirement it only 8 characters long. My domain controler is Windows 2012 R2 and we only have 01 DC at the moment. And I see you using vmail but dovecot userdb is lookup from AD. When use vmail setup, your user db is static and located somewhere belong to vmail:vmail